# Changing the Direction of an Object in a Diagonal orientation

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, shapes

I'm trying to make an object move in the shape of a triangle however, I'm running into some trouble with changing the orientation. I've been referencing my lecture notes but I can't seem to change what I want.

```
function aniLoop(){
    clear();
    circlesUpdate(aC);
    requestAnimationFrame(aniLoop)
}
function circlesUpdate(a){
    for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        circle(a[i]);
        updateData(a[i]);
    }
}
function circle(o){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(o.x, o.y, o.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsla("+o.c+", 100%, 50%, "+o.a+")";
    ctx.fill();
}
function randn(r){
    return Math.random()*r - r/2
}
function rand(r){
    return Math.random()*r
}
```

I'm trying to make a loop of the circle to move in a triangle starting from w/2 and h/5 of the canvas size.

```
function createData(num){
    for (var i = 0; i<num; i++){
        aC.push({
            x: w/2,
            dx: randn(0),
            y: h/5,
            dy: 2+rand(3),
            r: 50,
            c: 200+rand(60),
            a: 0.5,
        })
    }
}
function clear(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
function updateData(o){
    var i;
    o.x += o.dx;
    o.y += o.dy;
    o.a -= o.da;  
    if(o.x > w || o.x < 0){
        o.dx *= -1;
    }
    if(o.y > h || o.y < 0){
        o.dy *= -1;
    }
}
```

I know that the function is set up so that the circle starts from w/2,h/5 and moves down then bounces back up, but I'm not sure how to change that so the circle moves in a triangle orientation from the top corner to the bottom left to the bottom right and back to the top corner.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly...
You want to create an animation where a circle moves in a triangle loop.

I see too much code on that example, no clue why we need random for this, also it does not show how/where the `createData` function is used...

Here is what I would do:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var i = 0, n = 1
var points = [[10,10], [80,10], [10,80]]
var speed  = [  [1,0], [-1, 1],  [0,-1]]
var p = points[i]

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p[0], p[1], 5, 2* Math.PI, 0);
  ctx.fill()
  
  p = [p[0]+speed[i][0], p[1]+speed[i][1]]
  if (Math.hypot(p[0]-points[n][0], p[1]-points[n][1]) < 2) {
    i = n
    n = (n+1) % points.length
  }  
}

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=150 height=150></canvas>
```

You don't really specify what type of triangle so for simplicity, I coded a right triangle...
On the `points = [[10,10], [80,10], [10,80]]`
those are the corners of our triangle

And on `speed  = [  [1,0], [-1, 1],  [0,-1]]`
that is the speed for our object *(wanna go faster change those 1 to 2)*

---

We have minimal math:
`p = [p[0]+speed[i][0], p[1]+speed[i][1]]`
Just increasing the position by current speed

And on the if statement:
`if (Math.hypot(p[0]-points[n][0], p[1]-points[n][1]) < 2)`
We are just checking the distance to the next point, if we are less than 2 pixels away we will change our "current" index to next `i = n`